# What is the board game played in Houseki no Kuni?

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to identify this game from Houseki no Kuni, a buddhism-inspired manga.
My English is so poor I can't describe this game and "google" it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you name the manga?

Comment: This is Houseki no Kuni, chapter 43 (currently in Japanese ( http://www.mediafire.com/download/p6zvh5nutxdx55x/Houseki_no_Kuni_2016-06.zip ), will be translated into Russian in day or two)

Comment: Any reason to assume this is a real game and not something invented specially for the manga? (I see one player has tentacles instead of hands, so I guess some elements are fictional...)

Comment: @G0BLiN Sorry, threre is no reason to assume this is a real game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking for the name of a fictional game that has no name.

Comment: @bwarner It could also seem to be asking about a real game with a name. Unless someone can verify this is a fictional game, I think this should remain open.

Comment: Shouldn't the burden of proof be on the asker, who has already stated that they have "no reason to assume this is a real game"?

Comment: We suggest you may be able to find a suitable answer for this on [anime.se]; followers of that manga will very likely be able to assist you better than us.

Answer (score -1):

the bottom picture looks like Go, but with an unusual shape for a board
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)

Comment: This seems unlikely: While there are Go variants with odd-shaped and odd-sized boards, from the pictures there's also at least three different piece types (round, triangular, square). Only common variant I can think of in that vein is three-player go, if one assumes different shapes instead of different colors to differentiate players.