# Search for a board game

Tags: identify-this-game

What board game might this guy be playing?

[image: Guy carrying a board game]

This is part of a riddle, I feel the pattern reminds me of something but I can't get a grip on it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Maybe a boardgame version of Tetris ;-).

Comment: @ToonKrijthe This is indeed a good guess, but it was hinted, that this is not the case. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can we see the original riddle?

Comment: I think that's just a crossword puzzle.  So based on that it would be scrabble.  Is this from a boardgaming source?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence this is a real board game, following the same close reason as [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29833/what-is-the-board-game-played-in-houseki-no-kuni).

Comment: @SocioMatt I at least expected that someone mentions hnefatafl or the like, or maybe tawlbwrdd... This would have been the obvious guesses, but unfortunately it is neither of both. However, guessing these would show a lot more proficiency than simply voting to close this question.

Comment: My vote to close is based on the fact that answers would just be guesses. Trying to determine a board game using only a drawn picture of a fraction of the board, with no other information, isn't supportable by evidence or expertise. And, as I pointed out in my previous comment, there is a precedent for closing these questions.

Comment: @ScottMatt So, five people voting to close a question then decide for all future, that this kind of questions always has to be closed? This is barely a democratic process...

Answer (score 2):

It could conceivably be **[Blokus](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2453/blokus)**, or possibly a black and white variant of it.

In Blokus you place shapes of your colour such that one (or more) corner(s) of the shape you place must touch a corner(s) of an existing piece of your colour, but such that no edges of your colour touch any other edges of your colour.